# Issue with Touch and slide in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game where you slide some stuff and when you find the special one. Instead of sliding you need to just tap on it. For this I created the following code, but it's not working as I wanted to:

```
void Update()
 {
     if (Input.touchCount > 0)
     {
         // get the first one
         Touch firstTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);

         // if it began this frame
         if (firstTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
         {
             if (firstTouch.position.x > screenCenter)
             {
                 Anim.SetBool("Swiper", true);
                 print("Swipe");
             }
         }
         else if (firstTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
         {
             if (E.FInt == 1)
             {
                 //Sound
                 print("Debugged");
                 SceneManager.LoadScene(Beh.SceneArray[Beh.Counter]);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

The problem here is that it executes the code of when you slide even if you just tap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets look at this section:

```
     // if it began this frame
     if (firstTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
     {
         if (firstTouch.position.x > screenCenter)
         {
             Anim.SetBool("Swiper", true);
             print("Swipe");
         }
     }
```

If the touch-phase is `Began` and the the touch is on the right side of the screen, then CLEARLY it's a swipe.

No, no its not. It's a touch that is just beginning. It hasn't had a chance to be swiped yet.